# Website Outputting HTML Number Instead of Asian Characters

Tags: html, facebook-like, twig

My website is being rendered in Twig. I have a meta tag that is rendering out HTML Numbers instead of the actual Chinese character. I am wondering how would I get it to render the actual Chinese character?

I've noticed that if I do this with a `<p>`, the actual source code does render with HTML Numbers, but it looks like the browser translates it to the actual Chinese character.

Note that the issue I have here is with Facebook. When Facebook scrapes my page, they read the `og:description` value which is presented as HTML entities.

code: `<meta name="og:description" content="{{ product.description }}"/>`

actual output: 
`<meta name="og:description" content="&#28858;&#12298;&#27054;&#35709;&#21235;&#31456;&#65306;&#37941;&#34880;&#24717;"/>`

expected output:
`<meta name="og:description" content="為《榮譽"/>`

Comment: These are called HTML entities.  Any HTML parser will read them as the correct character; you don't actually have a problem.

Comment: @SLaks Unfortunately, Facebook is not reading them properly. When Facebook scrapes my page for the description, Facebook grabs these HTML entities instead.

Comment: How do you enter Chinese characters in the first place? Who don’t you just copy and paste them into the `meta` tag?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The content is not entered as such in our database. They are entered in as HTML entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure the page is UTF-8 encoded and declared as UTF-8. See W3C material on [character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset) if needed.

Then, convert the character references like `#28858;` to corresponding characters, in UTF-8 encoding, when generating the HTML document using the database. In PHP, you can use [`mb_decode_numericentity`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-decode-numericentity.php) for this.